# The mouth of my co-worker stinks so strongly, that I can't stay 2m from him

Tags: colleagues

...but we are talking a lot, and he is mostly much much closer.

I don't know what to do. Now he has left my desk around 10 minutes ago, but I still can feel the odor of his mouth.

I don't have any idea, what to do. How could I start a new work week Monday?

It is not a simple case, it is a very urgent matter, it is more than uncomfortable, it is foul.

Comment: @JeffO It is not surely personal hygiene matter. It may be also some backterial infection in his mouth. If somebodys body stinks, then he doesn't bath, it is clear. But if somebodys mouth, it can have also different reasons.

Comment: When he's not at his desk, drop him an anonymous gift of altoids. You might get lucky and he'll take a hint.

Comment: @MorningStar while it's not necessarily a matter of hygiene, the answers in that question are still good and apply to the problem.

Comment: https://www.betterhealth.vic.gov.au/health/conditionsandtreatments/halitosis-or-bad-breath - it could be hygiene, or could be other factors, but the symptom is treatable...

Comment: @MorningStar - I'd expect a bacterial infection of the mouth to be temporary unless untreated which for all practical purposes of having bad breath all the time is just about the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple, keep a jar of mints on your desk.  When the co-worker comes over to talk to you, take one yourself, and offer your co-worker one.   That way you aren't making a comment on your co-worker, only being nice, and you can ensure no-one is having the same issue with you.

Problem solved.

Comment: your lucky you squeezed this in before it was marked as duplicate.  ;-)

Comment: If it's just bad breath, then sure mints are great. If it's an infection or tonsil stones, he needs to regularly irrigate his tonsils and rinse with Biotene.

Comment: I'd like to see this happen _every time_ they pop over. Cost a fortune in mints! ;-)

Comment: @MisterPositive - luck has nothing to do with my friend ;)

Comment: @Bugs - search for "Yupik Scotch Mints, 1Kg" on the A-Z seller, cost $9 here in Canada, should last a while.

Comment: In this case, mint is probably not a solution, because his mouth was far too foul to be suppressed by mint.